# How to preform data driven testing using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Give some examples for data driven testing using selenium web driver in java

Answer (score 0):

Selenium isn't responsible for data driven testing, the unit test framework you use is. I don't use Java but here is how it could look in C#.

```
    [Row("Test1")]
    [Row("Test2")]
    [Row("Test3")]
    [Row("Test4")]
    [Row("Test5")]
    [Row("Test6")]
    [Row("Test7")]
    [Row("Test8")]
    [Row("Test9")]
    public void SomeTest(string dataDriven)
    {
                       // Test code that can use the dataDriven string for whatever
    }
```

You can replace the rows with a reference to a cvs or similar aswell.

NOTE: This is using MBUnit